# Difference between field and property in OrientDB

Tags: properties, field, orientdb

I am using OrientDB for the first time. I read that this database operates in a schema less mode.

Although there seems to be some confusion between **Field** and **Property**. What is the difference between these two?

The ALTER command does work on fields but fields are shown under the property name in OrientDB studio in query results. Field operations are done through UPDATE. Am I missing something. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

The field and property are the same thing in OrientDB.

When you use UPDATE you should not specify the word property or field, the property is just used in ALTER queries, for example ALTER PROPETY, see:

https://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-Alter-Property.html

and

https://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-Update.html

Comment: I think there has to be a difference. Read [this](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/3134) issue thread on github. I was also getting a similar error but managed to solve it. Moreover there cannot be ALTER and UPDATE just for the sake of having it.

Comment: @NishantKumar you're referencing to an issue about a super old version! 1.7.9!

Comment: @IvanMainetti yes the issue is old, but I was just try to show that there indeed is a difference between property and field in OrientDB.

Comment: fact is that properties and fields are the same thing in OrientDB.